# Fetch Row of Value From Other Spreadsheet Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to access data from one Google Spreadsheet on another using strictly formulas.

Currently, I am able to import data using the `=IMPORTRANGE()`, but need to take this a couple steps further.

The data that I have looks like this:

Spreadsheet 1: Each sheet is for a different day, and has people and the number of fruits they pick from a farm (this is example data). However, the people are not necessarily organized exactly the same way on each day.

Spreadsheet 2: Each sheet is organized by person. Row A has the day (which will be used to lookup from the other spreadsheet), and a function exists in the second spreadsheet to find the persons name (`=sheetName()`).

What I have so far is [for Spreadsheet 2]:

`=IMPORTRANGE(Master!A1, A2 & "!B2")`

Where `Master!A1` refers to the link of the other spreadsheet, `A2` refers to the Day1. However, the part I am looking to replace is the 2 in the `B2` to find the row of the person's name in the sheet Day1 from the first spreadsheet.

I feel like I have to do something like this:

`=IMPORTRANGE(Master!A1, A2 & "!B" & MATCH(IMPORTRANGE(Master!A1,A2 & "!B1:B100"),sheetName(),0))`

, but this gives me the error that it "Did not find value 'Apples' in match evaluation"

Here is the example folder with the two spreadsheets.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B8lJN2vmKeTBV1JYR2ZoZlVfQUU

All help is appreciated!

Comment: If you don't use Excel, don't tag with Excel. Removing the Excel tag from your question.

Comment: Please make the spreadsheet public, you probably want to run a filter on the transposed importrange result

Answer (score -1):

I can't find the sample data that you attached but here's what you need to do.
1. Link of the other spreadsheet
2. Name of the sheet to import from
3. `=importrange(link,sheet!A:D)` [for the sake of an example]
4. `=query(importrange(link, sheet!A:D),"select * where Col1 = 'Person's_Name' ",1)`
Share a sheet if you are not able to put it together on your data. Cheers!!